# Makefile: Avoid recompilation of a cloned repository

Tags: makefile, directory, gnu-make

I'm trying to clone a repository from git and compile it locally. The relevant part of the Makefile is pasted below.

```
BUILDDIR = $(PWD)/build 
# rest of the Makefile 
...
all: release 

release: $(BUILDDIR)/buildr/Makedir $(BUILDDIR)/depqbf

$(BUILDDIR)/buildr/Makedir: 
    mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)/buildr

$(BUILDDIR)/depqbf: 
    cd $(BUILDDIR); rm -rf depqbf; git clone git@github.com:lonsing/depqbf.git 
    cd $(BUILDDIR)/depqbf;./compile.sh
```

The problem is if I use **rm -rf depqbf**, the compilation process happens everytime I run make.

If I remove it, and perform **make** again

> fatal: destination path 'depqbf' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Is it possible to only clone and compile if the directory is not present.

Comment: Why do you have `$(BUILDDIR)/depqbf/depqbf` instead of just `$(BUILDDIR)/depqbf`?

Comment: That was by mistake. Let me remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the compilation process happens everytime I run make

The target of your recipe:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/depqbf/depqbf:
    cd $(BUILDDIR); rm -rf depqbf; git clone git@github.com:lonsing/depqbf.git
    cd $(BUILDDIR)/depqbf;./compile.sh
```

is the file `$(BUILDDIR)/depqbf/depqbf`. You are telling Make that, if the target `$(BUILDDIR)/depqbf/depqbf`
does not exist, then Make is to make the target by running the commands:

```
cd $(BUILDDIR); rm -rf depqbf; git clone git@github.com:lonsing/depqbf.git
cd $(BUILDDIR)/depqbf;./compile.sh
```

But those commands never create a file called `$(BUILDDIR)/depqbf/depqbf`. They
never make the target.

So every time Make considers the target it will decide that it has to made, by
running those commands.

If you remove `rm -rf depqbf`, then when Make attempts the target:

```
fatal: destination path 'depqbf' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Naturally, because you cannot clone into an existing non empty-directory. This is
not connected with the fact that the recipe is always being run. It is always being run
because it never makes its target.

Your other recipe:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/buildr/Makedir:
    mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)/buildr
```

likewise is one that that never makes it target. The command:

```
mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)/buildr
```

will never create the file `$(BUILDDIR)/buildr/Makedir`. I do not see the purpose
of this recipe, so I'll assume it is just supposed to create the file
`$(BUILDDIR)/buildr/Makedir` if it does not exist, for some reason.

Then this makefile will attempt to make the targets if and only if they don't exist:

**Makefile**

```
BUILDDIR := $(PWD)/build

.PHONY: all release

all: release

release: $(BUILDDIR)/buildr/Makedir $(BUILDDIR)/depqbf

$(BUILDDIR)/buildr/Makedir: | $(BUILDDIR)/buildr
    touch $@

$(BUILDDIR)/depqbf: | $(BUILDDIR)
    cd $(dir $@); git clone git@github.com:lonsing/depqbf.git 
    cd $@; ./compile.sh

$(BUILDDIR) $(BUILDDIR)/buildr:
    mkdir -p $@
```

Useful references in [The GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html):-

- [An Introduction to Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction)
- [Phony Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)
- [Types of Prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)
- [Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination. Very clear now.